# Correct output when .isEmpty != nil but no output in the else statement

Tags: swift

This function does print out "Enter a number!" when nothing is entered into the textField but if I DO put something in the textField it still prints out "Enter a number!"  I obviously want it to print out "Oh, you're (newAge)" when a number is entered in. What am I missing?

```
Swift 2.0

@IBAction func SubmitAgeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

let newAge = String(textField.text!)

if ((textField.text?.isEmpty) != nil) {
        label.text = "Enter a number!"
    }
    else {

        label.text = "Oh, you're \(newAge)" // This isn't printing out.

        return()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your code you check if the text is there and returns something at all. Which both "" as well as a non empty string do. namely a Bool.

so `if let text = textField.text where !text.isEmpty)`

Comment: Yes I tried it with quotes and it works but I wanted to use the isEmpty method because I've never used it before. Are you saying I need to add "-> BOOL"? Not quite following.

Comment: You check if isEmpty returns nil, but it only returns 'false' or 'true'. so != nil should be != false

Comment: Thanks Simon that cleared it up. It works now. `if ((inputField.text?.isEmpty) != false)`. Xcode wasn't giving any errors so it was confusing.